# Is it possible to create a control once and have it generated everytime it is needed?

Tags: wpf, dynamic, components

Say for example you have a stackpanel that you would like to programmatically add buttons to.

The code behind for the button generation and addition to the stackpanel is:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Content = "Button";
button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
button.Name = "Button" + i
stackPanel1.Children.Add(button);
```

My question is - Is it possible to generate the button once and have it as some kind of template that can be added to the stackpanel whenever it is needed without going through the generation code again?

Answer (score 0):

In WPF each UIElement can only be the logical child of one control at any given time, see [WPF Error: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/wpf-error-specified-element-is-already-the-logical-child-of-another-element-disconnect-it-first/), so no you can't use the same button and add it to another control later on, unless you're sure you've gotten rid of that stackpanel

But, you can do recycling. See [Optimizing Performance: Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx). especially if you are willing to override `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` of you stackpanel

I've actually written such a recycler because I had grids with many controls, and I wanted to implement some kind of virtualizing grid. These are the main methods of my class:

```
internal class Recycler
{
    private UIElementCollection _children;

    public Recycler(UIElementCollection children)
    {
         _children = children;
         //You need this because you're not going to remove any
         //UIElement from your control without calling this class
    }

    public void Recycle(UIElement uie)
    {
        //Keep this element for recycling, remove it from Children
    }

    public UIElement GiveMeAnElement(Type type)
    {
        //Return one of the elements you kept of this type, or
        //if none remain create one using the default constructor
    }
}
```